# Jquery/Javascript Setting the attribute value of a textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a

```
<input type='text' id='text' value='' />
```

How do I programmatically set the value attrribute using JQuery/Javascript

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The simple easy way is:

```
$("#text").val ("foo");
```

Answer (score 22):

It's as easy as this:

```
$("#text").attr("value", "some value");
```

Comment: What did I get downvoted for? My answer is correct, even if it isn't the absolute shortest way to do it.

Comment: dunno, and asker should be aware that your solution can be used for any attributes

Comment: not sure however .val is quicker and preferred route than the attr.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. I just didn't know it existed (so I learned something). I just think it's kind of dumb for someone to downvote an answer that is correct.

Comment: @redsquare('.yourFirstComment') I agree completely that val() should be (is) the preferred route (no magic strings etc). I thought it is interesting enough to point out to the asker who probably is quite new to jquery

Comment: I didn't up or down vote your response, but its good to know that this works for every attribute

Answer (score 13):

The Javascript would be:

```
document.getElementById('text').value = 'Blahblah';
```

Answer (score 9):

In jQuery, you'd do it like this:

`$("#text").val("my new value");`

You might also want to read the [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val#val) on this topic

Without jQuery:

`document.getElementById("text").setAttribute("value", "my new value");`

Hope that helps.