# How can I show url of current page inside a text input for user to copy?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to achieve something similar to what youtube has where when you press share button you can actually see url of current page inside some sort of text input and actually copy it etc. How can this be done with jQuery?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-with-javascript searching faster than asking

Comment: He's not asking how to get the current URL (which even makes my answer wrong). He's asking how to get that into some input via jQuery.

Comment: @Renan.. This could have helped him.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222316/jquery-javascript-setting-the-attribute-value-of-a-textfield

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [window.location.href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) would suffice.

**Edit:** as other have said:

```
$('#inputId').val(window.location);
```

Kudos for all the other guys who got that right before I did.

Comment: Mohammad's answer is more complete than mine.

Answer (score 3):

To get the path, you can use window.location.href:

```
var url = window.location.href;
$('#yor_text_id').val(url);
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('input').val(window.location.href);
```

And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n4Yxa/) it is in action.

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uSq6p/)

```
$("a").click(function() {
  $("input").val(window.location.href);
});
```

Comment: I think he wants the full URL, not the relative one.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#YourTextInputID").val(window.location.href);
```

Comment: this inserts page url inside #YourTextInputId correct? Or do I need to use window.location.href ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#input").val(window.location);
```

The jQuery way, though not needed.

```
$('input').val($(window).attr('location'));
```

Comment: That returns an object, not a string.

Comment: @Renan ... an object with a `.toString()` method set to return the href property...

Comment: You're right. My bad.